# How can put .vimrc and viminfo into .vim directory?

Tags: vimrc

All the vim related files installed on /usr/share/vim/vim74.

```
cd /home/debian8/
ls  .vim*
.viminfo  .vimrc
```

To create .vim directory to install  some plugin for customization.

```
mkdir  .vim
mkdir  .vim/plugin
mkdir  .vim/autoload
```

If .viminfo and .vimrc are moved into .vim directory directly, then the configuration for vim can't be read.

How can .vimrc and viminfo be relocated into the .vim directory?

Comment: why do you want to? That's not where they are supposed to go.

Comment: @HerbWolfe That's not really true: see `:help .vimrc`. One good reason to do so (at least for .vimrc) is so you have your entire vim config in a single directory, making it easier to put in source control or for syncing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note:** @Rich's answer is more correct, but this is still a valid way to set a "default" arbitrary path for `vimrc`.

The easiest way to have a custom `vimrc` location is to use the `VIMINIT` environment variable:

```
export VIMINIT="source ~/.vim/vimrc"
```

See `:h VIMINIT`

It's ignored when using `vim -u ~/some/other/vimrc`

As for `viminfo`, you need to add this to your `vimrc` file:

```
set viminfo+=n~/.vim/viminfo
```

See `:h 'viminfo'`

Answer (score 22):

You don't need any shell configuration to store your `.vimrc` file in the `.vim` directory. You just need to remove the `.` or `_` from the filename.

Vim looks in the following locations by default on startup:

On Unix (including OS X/macOS):

```
~/.vim/vimrc
```

On Windows:

```
%HOMEPATH%\vimfiles\vimrc
```

See section **II** of `:help .vimrc` for the documentation on this.

As [@Tommy A has already explained](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11881/343), you can set the location of the `viminfo` file by adding the following command to your `vimrc`:

```
set viminfo+=n~/.vim/viminfo
```

Comment: Totally right.  I missed that part of the docs because I'm using Neovim.

Answer (score 18):

## What if you want to move everything?

Although the answers here are correct, they miss something. The OP's question didn't ask about how to change everything, just `.vimrc` and `.viminfo`.

Then to achieve this we need special attention to the `autoload` folder and to the various plugins folders.

I wanted to move all `vim` configurations to the more (now) standard directory `.config` that is supposed to be used by all applications, even than some of them do not use it and pollute the HOME folder.

To be able to move all stuff vim needs to `.config/vim`, you need to make the following changes:

- on your `~/.bashrc`, add: `export VIMINIT="source ~/.config/vim/vimrc"`

  - This is to instruct `vim` where to find your new `vimrc` configuration file
- on your `~/.config/vim/vimrc` file, **before** your plugin manager, set the `autoload` directory adding: `set runtimepath+=~/.config/vim,~/.config/vim/after`

  - This will instruct `vim` to run files and scripts found in those paths. The current `runtimepath` can be seen with the command `set runtimepath?` and it will probably show something like `~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after`. You need to add the new folders in that list, without compromising the old folders, as they may have lots of default scripts. You don't need `~/.vim` and `~/.vim/after`, as they don't exist, but no harm letting the path as is, and just add what you need.
  - Edited: In case your spell checker can't find the path, it is because the first directory in the list `runtimepath` is important and yours is probably out of order (you can check with `:set runtimepath?`). In this case you need to enforce the order by using the following 3 lines instead of the above:

    ```
    let rtp=&runtimepath
    set runtimepath=~/.config/vim
    let &runtimepath.=','.rtp.',~/.config/vim/after'
    ```
- also on your `vimrc` file, add: `set viminfo+=n~/.config/vim/viminfo`

  - This will tell `vim` to write the old `~/.viminfo` file in the new location, now without the prefixed dot.

Almost done. Lets talk about plugins now, with, of course, a great plugin manager. If you never tried it, it is time to free yourself from the plugin madness and let a manager do the job.

- If you don't have one installed, use the following lines in your `~/.config/vim/vimrc` file to download and auto-install it:

```
    if empty(glob('~/.config/vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
       silent !curl -fLo ~/.config/vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
         \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
       autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
    endif
```

This will download and install your plugin manager. After that, the following lines will download and install a plugin of your choice (examplified with `drbeco/vimtemplates` and `ajh16/VimCompleteMe` plugins. You can add more as you wish.):

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/vim/plugged')
Plug 'drbeco/vimtemplates'
Plug 'ajh17/VimCompletesMe'
call plug#end()
```

This call will create folders like `~/.config/vim/plugged/vimtemplates` and `~/.config/vim/plugged/VimCompletesMe`, and so on, for each plugin.

So now, even the plugins are all organized inside `~/.config/vim`, and that really cleans the `HOME` directory.

## Bonus: swap, backup and undo files

- Move also `swapfiles` adding to your now `~/.config/vim/vimrc` file: `set directory=~/.config/vim/swap//,.,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp`

  - You need to create the directory with: `mkdir ~/.config/vim/swap`
  - You can also avoid them by using: `set noswapfile`
- Move the backup files to a central location adding to your `vimrc` file: `set backupdir=~/.config/vim/backup//,.,~/tmp,~/`

  - You need to create the directory with: `mkdir ~/.config/vim/backup`
  - Or just avoid them by using: `set nobackup`
- Move the `undo` files adding to your `vimrc` the line: `set undodir=~/.config/vim/undo//,.`

  - You need to create the directory with: `mkdir ~/.config/vim/undo`
  - Or avoid them using: `set noundofile`

Note: the `//` at the end instructs `vim` to save also the directory path in the filename. Something like `home%documents%letter2mama.tex.swp` will be used.

Note 2: edited explanation about `runtimepath` as the spell checker may get confused otherwise.

## Extra bonus: some plugins may need help

If you use some plugins that insist to add files to `~/.vim`, you may need to read the doc for each one and come up with a solution. For example:

- [Coc](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/coc-nvim) - For `VimPlug` manager, install with `Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}`; the problem is that, without proper setup it attempts to read coc-settings.json from `~/.vim`. There are two solutions:

  - Add `export VIMCONFIG="$HOME/.config/vim"` to your `/etc/profile` (or `zprofile` for zsh); or
  - Add `g:coc_config_home="~/.config/vim"` to your `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` config file

Comment: This is a great answer, but it's an answer to a different question. This question is about how to move the `.vimrc` and `.viminfo` file into the `.vim` directory (which is itself in the normal location). The existing answers don't discuss `.vim/autoload` because the OP doesn't want to move that directory.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. But to be honest, when I was trying that myself, googling, I ended up here. So, lets say, even if this answer is not the "accepted" one, it will still help other googlers that ended up here as myself. (edited the intro anyway, to avoid confusion)

Comment: It helped me, thanks beco!

Answer (score 2):

I use symbolic link.

`ln -s ~/.vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

For me hard links are the best for this purpose,

```
ln ~/.vimrc .vim/.vimrc
```

This will let you edit any of them and if you have been using git for storing  .vim
We can just create after pulling it from github.

Comment: What is the advantage of using a hard link over a symbolic link in this case?

Comment: @MartinTournoji  For filesystem that does not support symbolic link, such as NTFS before Windows Vista.