# Moving .viminfo file to .vim dir

Tags: vimrc, viminfo

According to [this FAQ](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11879/how-can-put-vimrc-and-viminfo-into-vim-directory) for moving .viminfo file to .vim dir we should add `viminfo+=n~/.vim/viminfo` to vimrc file but when I put this line in my vimrc, every time I open vim, it will return this: `E492: Not an editor command: viminfo+=n~/.vim/viminfo` But I don't know why and how can I fix it, so please let me know that and don't mark [duplicate] on this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viminfo` is an option, @Tommy A forgot the keyword `set` in his command:

```
set viminfo+=n~/.vim/viminfo
```

should work properly. If you read [`:h 'viminfo'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27viminfo%27) you can see an example:

```
:set viminfo='50,<1000,s100,:0,n~/vim/viminfo
```

*Edit* As @Carpetsmoker mentioned it in the comments, neovim has a different format for these options so one should use the following:

```
if has('nvim') | let &viminfo .= '.nvim' | endif
```

Comment: If you care about Vim/Neovim compatibility then you need to do something like: `if has('nvim') | let &viminfo .= '.nvim' | endif`, as Neovim uses a different format.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I don't use neovim but that's good to know thank you!

Comment: Note, recent version of Vim also have the 'viminfofile' setting

Answer (score 1):

I know its quite a while now, but I am just mentioning this for future readers.

I was facing the same issue while trying to change the location for viminfo file in vimrc. At last setting the value of `viminfofile` option worked for me.

Added the following to my vimrc:

```
set viminfofile=D:\vim\viminfo
```

*It works for me on windows with vim 8.2*

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!